# Trying to iterate Array of objects from props but getting undefined (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From my home component I'm trying to pass a prop to a modal component with a product object like this:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../helpers/auth';
import EditProductModal from './EditProductModal';

export default function Home(){


    const [product,setProduct]= useState({})

 
    const {products} = useSelector(state=>state.products) ;

    return(
    <>
        <div className='container mt-5'>
            <div className="row">
                {products.map(product=>(
                 <div key={product._id} className="col">
                    <div  className="card mb-4" style={{width: '18rem'}}>
                         <Link to={{pathname: '/product', state:{product: product}}} ><img className="card-img-top" src={`/uploads/${product.productPhoto}`} style={{height:'15rem'}} alt=""/></Link>
                         <div className="card-body">
                            <h4 className="card-title text-primary">{product.name}</h4>
                            <h5>{product.price}<i className="fas fa-euro-sign"/></h5>
                            {isAuthenticated().role===1 ? 
                            (<><button className='btn btn-outline-primary' data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editProduct" onClick={()=>setProduct(product)}><i class="fas fa-edit"/>        Edit</button>  
                            <button className='btn btn-outline-primary'><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"/>       Delete</button></>)
                            :
                            (<button className="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>)
                            }
                            
                        </div>                         
                    </div>
                </div>       
            ))}

          <EditProductModal product={product} />
              
            </div>

        </div>
```

Product looks like this:

```
{
name: '',
main_category:'',
sub_category:'',
price:'',
description:'',
sizes: [] //array of objects
}
```

In my EditProductModal component I can take all the values from product prop but when I try to iterate through the array of objects (sizes) with map I get "sizes is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ...

So @HichamELBSI actually helped me in some way. Not in my Home component but inside my EditProductModal I had to put:

```
{product.sizes && product.sizes.map ....}
```

and I managed to iterate the array as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The first render, product seems to equal to `{}` so, sizes will be undefined.

I think you will need to display the modal only if `product` is set

```
{product && <EditProductModal product={product} />}
```

Comment: I tried this with no result. In EditProductModal I destructure the product prop .
-When I ```console.log(product.sizes)``` I get the Array. 
-When I  ```console.log(product.sizes[0])``` I get product.sizes undefined.
I tried ```console.log(typeof product.sizes)``` and I got 'object'

Comment: I also did ```console.log(Array.isArray(product.sizes)``` and I got true

Answer (score 0):

Could it just be down to bad variable naming? You're setting `product` in state to `{}` and then using the same variable name `product` in the map of `products`. Even if it's not the cause, you're not making it easy for yourself or anyone else to debug.

You should also check whether you're actually getting the expected data from Redux. Based on this line `const {products} = useSelector(state=>state.products)` the shape of your store should resemble something like this since you're destructuring the object returned from the selector:

```js
{
  products: {
    products: [
      {...},
      {...},
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You are probably right about the naming but that wasn't the problem.